# melt command line player issue : interlacing not supported by codec

Tags: video, mlt

I installed melt (using MLT framework) in one of my Linux machine and is trying to perform a simple video editing operation. 
Following is the command I issued:

```
melt avformat-novalidate:clip1.mpeg -consumer avformat:clip1-grey.mpeg -verbose
```

The output video is not getting created properly and also it is giving an error like:

```
[mpeg1video @ 0x1b0a5910]interlacing not supported by codec
```

Do anybody know, why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this :

```
melt youravifile.flv -consumer avformat  frame_rate_num=30 -profile vcd_pal >output.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your video is not encoded properly because i have used it before for multiple codecs and multiple containers I haven't seen this error before.

try using different video codecs like mpeg4 or libx264. to know all the video codecs available

```
melt -query "video_codecs"
```

use video codec in your command like this

```
melt avformat-novalidate:clip1.mpeg -consumer avformat:clip1-grey.mpeg -vcodec=libx264 -verbose
```

you may need to change the file extension(container) depending on the codec you use like for h264 you would want to use avi or flv etc.